# Spoofed packet not forwarded through ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables, nat, spoofing

My network structure is as follows:

[Network structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxrnX.jpg)

### Win XP       <--------->                  Ubuntu                  <--------->       Kali

192.168.172.2                          192.168.170.1                 192.168.180.1                  192.168.180.2

My Ubuntu virtual machine has two network cards, each of which is located in a different subnet.
Also I have enabled IP Forwarding on the Ubuntu virtual machine.

In this structure, when I send a regular packet from Kali to Windows, it sends out with no problems.
But if I send a packet with spoofed IP, Ubuntu receives the packet (on Wireshark), but will not be sent to the Windows XP virtual machine.
Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps it's dropped due to an RPF failure, since the source of the packet is unknown - try adding a default route toward the Kali machine (if this doesn't help, try adding a specific route = spoofed IP)

Comment: @sergeyrar . Thanks for your helpful comment.
My problem was precisely because of the RPF failure.
I disabled the RPF on all Ubuntu ports, and my problem was fixed.